# Android: Click/Touch Management

Tags: android

Big Picture:

User is on their device home screen with an overlay from my application in an arbitrary corner. Overlay is small icon with no functionality (can register if it has been touched) other than presence.

Is it possible to know when the user has clicked OUTSIDE the overlay. I can tell when the user touches the overlay itself, but would like to know if the user has touched the screen but not the overlay?

Does not matter what is being touched, just if the screen is being touched on their device.

Also, same scenario, is it possible to know that the user has clicked a button? For instance, the user clicks the contacts application (or camera, or any application), is their a way to read that action? Do not care what application/button is clicked, just that one was clicked.

Just trying to learn what is possible, so please no need to write out code. Maybe just some pointers in the right direction. Thanks for input.

Comment: without having your overlay cover entire screen and intercepting **all** touch events, I don't think its possible

Answer (score 0):

For the first scenario you can try chat heads(like Facebook messanger) by using intentservice.